# I'm creating my module correctly?

Tags: module

I will need to integrate a Magento with another tool. I will override user (login, register, and personal information), cart and payment.

I created these modules:

**Mycompany_Base**: "Core" of my module with tabs and some other configurations.

**Mycompany_ModuleName**: In helper, I started to create all classes about an external SOAP connection, and get or send my information. I do not know if this is the correct way to do this, but all other modules would access this helper.

**Mycompany_ModuleNameUser**: overwrites models, blocks and controllers of the customer.

**Mycompany_ModuleNameCart**: overwrites models, blocks and controllers of the cart.

[...]

And I will create others similar to those.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this way also right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are going perfect 1 module for configuration setting 1 for overriding the cart and 1for customer even you can use event observer pattern too which can be helpful in many ways...